# The python and sqlite is returning the right data but HTML is not giving it right

Tags: html, sqlite, flask, jinja2

Taking something from a database if the method is get it just returns everything but if its post it returns the searched thing, when its get it works fine but when its post it gives the right value but html is not "deciphering" it?

HTML

```
{% for account in accounts %}
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">{{ account["email"] }}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{{ account["username"] }}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{{ account["password"] }}</th>
                    <th scope="col">{{ account["website"] }}</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
```

Ajax

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
            $(".table-body").empty();

            $.ajax ({
                method: "GET",
                url: "/manager",
                data: {search:$("#search").val()},
            })
        })
    })
```

PYTHON

```
@app.route("/manager", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def manager():
    loggedUser = session["loggedUser"][0]["username"]
    if request.method == "GET":
        accounts = db.execute("SELECT * FROM manager WHERE loggedUser = ?", loggedUser)
    else:
        form = request.form.get("search")
        accounts = db.execute("SELECT * FROM manager WHERE loggedUser = ? AND website LIKE ?", loggedUser, form + "%")

    print(accounts)
    return render_template("manager.html", accounts=accounts)
```

It gives the right results but it doesnt give it in the html unless its the get method

Output when POST

```
[{'id': 1, 'loggedUser': 'Hyde', 'username': None, 'email': None, 'password': '123', 'website': 'HydPass'}]
```

Structure

```
CREATE TABLE manager (id INTEGER, loggedUser TEXT NOT NULL, username, email, password TEXT NOT NULL, website TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Comment: What is the structure of the data returned? Could you share the value returned for `accounts`? As a side point, those two `SELECT` calls are not the same so you will likely be getting a different result/structure for each

Comment: Yes, I am aware they are not the same I'm getting a search value. For the structure,

- CREATE TABLE manager (id INTEGER, loggedUser TEXT NOT NULL, username, email, password TEXT NOT NULL, website TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id));

And it returns,

- [{'id': 1, 'loggedUser': 'Hyde', 'username': None, 'email': None, 'password': '123', 'website': 'HydPass'}]

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a formatted output for both use cases. Maybe a screenshot of both HTML outputs too

Comment: It actually might be noteworthy to say that i used ajax too

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
            $(".table-body").empty();

            $.ajax ({`
               method: "GET",
                url: "/manager",
                data: {search:$("#search").val()},
            })
        })
    })

Comment: Done, forgot I could edit honestly lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had to update it through AJAX

Ajax

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#search").on("input", function(e) {
            $(".table-body").empty();

            $.ajax ({
                method: "POST",
                url: "/manager",
                data: {search:$("#search").val()},
                success: function(data) {
                    // Clear the table
                    $(".table-body").empty();

                    // Iterate over the returned data and add a row for each account
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        var account = data[i];
                        var row = '<tr><th scope="col">' + account.email + '</th><th scope="col">' + account.username + '</th><th scope="col">' + account.password + '</th><th scope="col">' + account.website + '</th><th><input type="button" class="btn btn-primary p-2" value="Edit Account" name="edit"><input type="button" class="btn btn-warning p-1" value="Remove Account" name="remove"></th></tr>';
                        console.log(row)
                        $(".table-body").append(row);
                    }
                }
            })
        })
    })
```